# Why are trace-class unit-trace linear operators (like density operators) necessarily positive semidefinite?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Density operators in quantum mechanics are defined as trace-class unit-trace  linear operators on the Hilbert space. From this definition how can we conclude that they're necessarily positive semidefinite? Also, I'm not exactly sure how positive semidefiniteness is defined in infinite-dimensional spaces. Could someone explain?

Comment: Density operators in quantum mechanics are **defined** to be **positive semi-definite** trace-class operators of trace 1. Obviously there are trace class operators of trace 1 which lack the positivity criterion, e.g., $\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, so positivity has to be included in the definition to match the [probability interpretation of quantum states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is the same as in [the finite-dimensional case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix#Definitions).

Note that the general density matrix (an operator) is given by 
\begin{align}
\rho  = \sum_n \lambda_n |\psi_n\rangle \langle \psi_n|
\end{align}
where $\lambda_n\geq 0$ and $\sum_n\lambda_n = 1$.

We say that $\rho$ is positive semidefinite if
\begin{align}
\langle \Psi\mid \rho\mid\Psi\rangle \geq 0
\end{align} 
for all $\Psi$. Observe
\begin{align}
\langle \Psi\mid \rho\mid\Psi\rangle = \sum_n \lambda_n \langle \Psi \mid\psi_n\rangle \langle \psi_n\mid \Psi\rangle = \sum_n \lambda_n |\langle \psi_n \mid\Psi\rangle|^2\geq 0. 
\end{align}

Comment: That's the corollary of the definition.

Comment: Here is the definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix#Definitions

Comment: I am showing that the density matrix is positive semidefinite.

Comment: You ask why are density matrices necessarily positive semidefinite. I wrote down the definition of a general density matrix and the definition of positive semidefinite. Then I prove it.

Comment: if the $\psi_n $ are orthonormal, as they usually are, then $\{\lambda_n\} $ are the eigenvalues of $ \rho $.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Mathematically, yes. But the interpretation is very different.